# PowerPivot Multiple OData Services Related

Tags: wcf, odata, powerpivot

I'm playing around with OData with PowerPivot and I would like to know can I relate multiple OData services together?

I don't want to have one huge OData service as I want to roll this out for all of our internal systems.  I think one service would get messy.

Something like;
http://hosting/Sales.svc
http://hosting/Clients.svc
http://hosting/Finance.svc

With some relationships mapped within.

Anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks,
Mike Mengell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked it out.

In the PowerPivot window you have a design tab.  Select create relationship and you can select the enity which can be from any service, in my case it's 2 OData services.  Then you select the field for the relationship.

At the moment there doesn't seem to be any automatic relationship creation.  Which for me is probably a blocker on using this for my business.

But the process is painless if you understand about the relationships.

I'll write a blog post about this soon and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Easy; create three services with different Contexts / models.

--larsw

Comment: But how would they then relate to each other?  If I think in terms of tables then I would need some sort of join between them. Like Sales.ClientId = Clients.ClientId.